# AutoMapper between Model and ViewModel with multiple properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

Trying to map between a viewmodel and my model. In this scenario, i am getting taking data from a web service (creating a strongly typed view) and then loading it into a form. I then verify the client data from the web service, submit the form. It will do an insert or update depending on whether or not there's a record in my database.

I have been meaning to use AutoMapper for some time so this is my first experience with it. I want the properties from SearchResult to be mapped to my Client Model.

```
namespace Portal.ViewModels
{
public class ClientSearch
{
    public SearchForm searchForm { get; set; }
    public SearchResult searchResult { get; set; }
}

public class SearchForm
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string AccNumber { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string AccNumber { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
}

namespace Portal.Models
{
public class Client
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string AccNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
}
```

In my controller below, i'm trying to use AutoMapper to map the data in clientSearch to my Client model based on an HttpPost.

However, I'm getting the error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement when trying to create the Map. This is my attempt at using AutoMapper.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(ClientSearch clientSearch)
{
    // Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
    Mapper.CreateMap<ClientSearch, Client>;

    Client client = Mapper.Map<ClientSearch, Client>(clientSearch);
    ClientRepository.InsertOrUpdate(client);
    ClientRepository.Save();

}
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, your compiler told you about this. Basically, with `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` it told you that what you wrote is not a statement. That's actually pretty exact ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing your '()' after:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ClientSearch, Client>;
```

i.e. it should be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClientSearch, Client>();
```